# Example random variable $\xi$ such that $\xi$ and $\xi^2$ are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables

Find random variable $\xi$ such that $\xi$ and $\xi^2$ are independent.

Comment: Minimalist example: Let $X=0$ with probability $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\xi$ is independent of $\xi^2$, then for each $t$, 
$$\mathbb P\{\xi^2\leqslant t^2\}=\mathbb P\{-t\leqslant \xi \leqslant t,\xi^2\leqslant t^2\}=\mathbb P\{-t\leqslant \xi \leqslant t\}\mathbb P\{\xi^2\leqslant t^2\}=\mathbb P\{\xi^2\leqslant t^2\}^2,$$
which means that $\mathbb P\{\xi^2\leqslant t^2\}\in \{0,1\}$, hence $\xi^2$ is almost surely constant.

Conversely, if $\xi^2$ is almost surely constant, then $\xi$ is independent of $\xi^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial example is following: discrete two-values variable $P\{\xi = -1\} = p$, $P\{\xi = 1\} = (1-p)$.