# How to find all random variables $\xi$ such that $\xi$ and $\sin{\xi}$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

The problem is to find all possible random variables $\xi$ such that $\xi$ and $\sin{\xi}$ are independent.

I tried to use the approach similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271591/example-random-variable-xi-such-that-xi-and-xi2-are-independent), but get stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Precisely the same approach yields that $\sin \xi$ must be constant.

Comment: @zhoraster It's not clear though, why would $\xi \leq t$ imply $\sin{\xi} \leq t$ or why would $\sin{\xi} \leq t$ imply $\xi \leq \arcsin{t}$. Sinus is not monotonous function.

Comment: Try to approach a simpler problem first: if $\zeta$ is independent of $\zeta$, then it is constant (almost surely).

Comment: @zhoraster To be clear: I understood clearly the example from the link, and the only thing I can't understand is how to generalize this approach to sinus, since it's not monotonous. Therefore implications such as $P(\xi \leq t) = P(\xi \leq t, \sin{\xi} \leq \sin{t})$ would be invalid. At least, I can't realize why.

Comment: What about my simplified problem - with $\zeta$? Can you solve it?

Comment: @zhoraster I guess, for each $t$ it's true that $P(\xi \leq t) = P(\xi \leq t, \xi \leq t) = P(\xi \leq t)^2$, so $P(\xi \leq t) \in \{0, 1\}$, hence $\xi$ is constant.

Comment: Exactly (actually not, because I was speaking of $\zeta$). Anyway, if $\xi$ is independent of $\zeta = \sin \xi$, then $\zeta$ is independent of $\zeta$ etc.

Comment: @zhoraster Your statement is exactly what I don't know how to prove. And I don't see how it follows from your problem.

Comment: If $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent, then $h(\xi)$ and $g(\eta)$ are independent for any Borel $h,g$. This follows immediately from the definition of independence.

Comment: @zhoraster thanks, got it now!